# How can I turn kerning on by default in Powerpoint 2010?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, typography

I understand how to turn kerning on for individual blocks of text, or individual text boxes, in Powerpoint. However, it is off again by default on every new slide and every new text box.

How can I set it on by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this app-wide, but in each file (or template) you can create a text box, format it to taste (including kerning), then right click it and choose Set As Default Text.

Any new text boxes will have the same font/size/KERNING/etc as the one you set as default.

This applies only to text boxes, not text in shapes.  For those, the same trick applies, but after adding text to a shape, selecting it and setting kerning, etc., right click and choose Set As Default Shape.